# NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData will generate JSON object even if the JSON is invalid

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa, parsing

*NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData* will generate JSON object even if the JSON is invalid, also the option that is being used in *JSONObjectWithData* is **NSJSONReadingMutableContainers**:

1. it will create a JSON object with only the valid JSON object/array
2. If the typo (in the JSON) is at the end of the final parentheses (like a comma), the JSON object will be 100% valid AND the error pointer will be nil.
3. If the typo is in the middle of value/key (inside the JSON) this value won't be created to the corresponding value/key inside that object AND the error pointer won't be nil.
4. *NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject* can only validate JSON object (*NSArray* or *NSDictionary*) thus, (obviously) *NSString* representation of the JSON will always return false - in other words, creating a JSON object will always be valid using *JSONObjectWithData*.

So how can I truly validate a JSON in iOS/Objective-c ?

The invalid JSON - a comma in the end makes the JSON invalid (as mentioned in #2):

```
{
"A": [
    {
        "B": 1,
        "C": 2,
        "D": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    }
],
"test": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "id2": 2,
        "id3": 3,
        "B": [

        ],
        "C": [

        ],
        "D": "test msg",
        "E": 2,
        "F": "www.google.com",
        "G": [
            2,
            3
        ],
        "test2": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "id2": 2,
                "id3": 3,
                "B": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "id2": "2",
                        "id3": 3,
                        "B": 4
                    }
                ]
            },

        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Show the JSON and the `options` used.

Comment: please add your code and json formate. i think your json formate is incorrect.

Comment: Added - As you can see, if you delete the comma right in the end it will make the JSON valid. ATM it is invalid.
@trojanfoe, NSJSONReadingMutableContainers - Also, I have tried all the 3 options.

Comment: `"test2": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "id2": 2,
                "id3": 3,
                "B": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "id2": "2",
                        "id3": 3,
                        "B": 4
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]`
in this case remove "," because only 1 object in array not more than. @OhadM

Comment: Have you read the question ? I wrote that even if the JSON is invalid it will still parse it WITHOUT any errors. Kindly read the post again.

Comment: Well if it works it just means that `NSJSONSerialization` is being liberal with the spec.  It's designed to do its best to parse JSON, not to be a JSON linter.

Comment: @trojanfoe, exactly my thoughts - fool proof. But then again, I still need to validate my JSON and I am interested to know if Cocoa has a method for this issue.

Comment: Have you already tried the `isValidJSONObject:` class method of NSJSONSerialization? Does it return true?

Comment: @MrAsterisco, you mean to use *isValidJSONObject* on the result of *NSJSONSerialization* ? but if *NSJSONSerialization* creates the object with the JSON, whats the point of checking if it's valid ? It already created it so it must be valid, regardless if the JSON is valid or not.

Comment: @MrAsterisco, I have just tested your suggestion and it returned true on the invalid JSON.

Comment: @OhadM: my bad. I didn't read the documentation deeply enough to understand that this method only checks whether an arbitrary object can be converted to JSON, not the other way around.

Anyway, I suggest you to check out some good JSON validator: there are a few out there that might work. This is the first one that comes to my mind: https://github.com/samskiter/KiteJSONValidator.